# Reactjs not re-rendering after jquery/ajax response when 1st entering page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

EDIT 2: See my answer below for solution.

Currently the code will make a request with jquery, get a response and load the data into state just fine. However when I 1st enter the page EmployeesTable it will get rendered without any data and won't re-render after I get a successful response and do setState.

However what makes it even more confusing is this only happens the 1st time entering the page. If I click a Link to go to another page and then come back to this page, it then works correctly, rendering and displaying the correct data after getting the ajax response.

Any idea what I maybe doing wrong? Thanks.

```
module.exports = class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      employees: [],
      isLoading: true
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      this.loadEmployeesData()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <EmployeesTable isLoading={this.state.isLoading} employees={this.state.employees} />
    )
  }
  loadEmployeesData() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/employeelist/',
      datatype: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
      },
      success: function (res) {
        this.setState({ employees: res, isLoading: false })
      }.bind(this)
    })
  }
}

function EmployeesTable(props) {
  if (props.isLoading === true) {
        //return <Loading />
  }
  var employeesRows = []
  for (let e of props.employees) {
    employeesRows.push(
            <tr>
                <td>{e.first_name} {e.last_name}</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
        )
  }
  return (
        <div>
            <h2>Employees</h2>
            <table className="table table-responsive table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {employeesRows}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
  )
}
module.exports = EmployeesTable
```

EDIT: Just to test, I tried to do this.forceUpdate() in the success function of the ajax call, but still getting the same behavior.

Another thing I should have noted and what is even more confusing is in the parent of EmployeeList, I am doing something very similar and it's actually working correctly. Below is the parent and the code that is working correctly when 1st entering the page after the user first logs in. Both App and EmployeeList get called in {children}

```
module.exports = class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sidebar: '',
      icon: 'fa fa-angle-left',
      toggleShow: true,
      user: [],
      loggedIn: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: !!localStorage.token })
    if (localStorage.token) {
      this.loadUserData()
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!!localStorage.token !== this.state.loggedIn) {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: !!localStorage.token })
      if (localStorage.token) {
        this.loadUserData()
      }
    }
  }

  render() {

    var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        user: this.state.user
      })
    })

    return (
      <div className='main-container'>
        <Menu props={this.state} logoutHandler={() => this.logoutHandler()} />
        <div id="wrapper" className={this.state.sidebar}>
          <Header props={this.state} sidebarToggle={() => this.sidebarToggle()} />
          <div id="main" className="container-fluid">
            {children}
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  sidebarToggle() {
    if (this.state.toggleShow) {
      this.setState({
        sidebar: 'hide-sidebar',
        icon: 'fa fa-angle-right',
        toggleShow: false
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        sidebar: '',
        icon: 'fa fa-angle-left',
        toggleShow: true
      })
    }
  }

  logoutHandler() {
    this.setState({user: []})
    auth.logout()
    Router.browserHistory.push('/login')
  }

  loadUserData() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/myinfo/',
      datatype: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
      },
      success: function (res) {
        this.setState({ user: res })
      }.bind(this)
    })
  }
}

module.exports = class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
            <h1>Welcome {this.props.user.first_name}</h1>
            </div>
    )        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have the answer, but have no idea why or why it behaved this way. I have been testing in firefox and using firebug, for what ever reason when I have firebug open I get the behavior I described, but when it's not running, then everything runs fine.

Not sure if bug with react, firebug or just something else.